# PHP Contact form Validation / URL issue

Tags: php, validation, contact-form

I have a php contact form with validation but I have my .htaccess set so it strips the .php from the url so the url looks cleaner (like wp urls).  The form works great except that when the user commits a validation error and presses "submit", the form validates fine, but it reloads the url with the .php extension and so if they fix their errors and submit again, my "outside url" hacking php code kicks in and doesn't send the form because the url's no longer match.

How can I either perform the validation without the page "reloading" or make it validate and reload without the .php extension in the url??

PHP:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $fromErr = $messageErr = $subjectErr = $phoneErr = $verif_boxErr = "";
$inquiries = $name = $from = $subject = $message = $verif_box = "";
$errors  = 0;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //check if form has been submitted
  //Get the inquiries field
    $inquiries =$_POST['inquiries'];

      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = " * Name is missing";
        $errors  = 1;
        echo '<style type="text/css"> input#name {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            $errors  = 1;
            echo '<style type="text/css"> input#name {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["from"])) {
        $fromErr = " * Email is missing";
        $errors  = 1;
        echo '<style type="text/css"> input#from {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
    } else {
        $from = test_input($_POST["from"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $fromErr = "Invalid email format";
            $errors  = 1;
            echo '<style type="text/css"> input#from {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = " * Subject is missing";
        $errors  = 1;
        echo '<style type="text/css"> input#subject {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $messageErr = " * Message is missing";
        $errors  = 1;
        echo '<style type="text/css"> textarea#message {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["verif_box"])) {
        $verif_boxErr = " * Security code is missing";
        $errors       = 1;
        echo '<style type="text/css"> input#verif_box {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
    } else {
        $verif_box = test_input($_POST["verif_box"]);
        if (md5($verif_box) . 'a4xn' <> $_COOKIE['tntcon']) {
            $verif_boxErr = " * Security code does not match";
            $errors       = 1;
            echo '<style type="text/css"> input#verif_box {border: 1px solid #F00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5pt .1pt #F00 inset;}</style>';
        }
    }
    if ($errors == 0) { // all fields successfullty validated. final hack check before sending email:
        // Stop the form being used from an external URL        
        $referer  = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . ".php";  // Get the referring URL        
        $this_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];    // Get the URL of this page
        // If the referring URL and the URL of this page don't match then
        // display a message and don't send the email.
        if ($referer != $this_url) {
            echo "You do not have permission to use this script from another URL, nice hacking attempt moron.";
            exit;
        } else {   // send the email
            $message = "Subject: " . $subject . "\n\nMessage: " . $message;
            $message = "Inquiry: " . $inquiries . "\n" . $message;
            $message = "Name: " . $name . "\n" . $message;
            $message = "From: " . $from . "\n" . $message;
            mail("milkytech@gmail.com", 'ContactUs: ' . $subject, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n\n" . $message, "From: Contact@AntiqueCafeBakery.com");            
            setcookie('tntcon', '');    // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
            header('Location: success');    // redirect to success page
            exit();
        }
    }
}
function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);    // strip unnecessary characters (extra space, tab, newline) from the user input data
    $data = stripslashes($data);    // remove backslashes (\) from the user input data
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);    // pass all variables through PHP's htmlspecialchars() function
    return $data;
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
       <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="contactform">
            <div>
                <label for="name"><strong>Inquries:</strong></label>
                <select name="inquiries" id="inquiries">
                  <option value="Catering">Catering</option>
                  <option value="Cookie Gift Tins">Cookie Gift Tins</option>
                  <option value="Retail Stores">Retail Stores</option>
                  <option value="Employment">Employment</option>
                  <option value="Investment">Investment</option>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="name"><strong>Name:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email"><strong>Email:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="from" id="from" value="<?php echo $from;?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $fromErr;?></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="subject"><strong>Subject:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="subject" id="subject" value="<?php echo $subject;?>" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="message"><strong>Message:</strong></label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="69" name="message" id="message"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="verif">
                <span>Captcha Code:</span>
                <input name="verif_box" type="text" size="10" id="verif_box"/>
                <img id="imageid" class="verifbox" src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image, type it in the box" />
                <input type="button" value="Reload Captcha" id="reload" onclick="reloadImg()" />

                <span class="error"><?php echo $verif_boxErr;?></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" />
                <br /><br />
            </div> <!--end form-->
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  I went back to w3 School to see exactly what `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` does in form validation and it says this:

> What is the `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` variable?
>   The `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is a super global variable that returns the filename of the currently executing script.
>
> What is the `htmlspecialchars()` function?
>   The `htmlspecialchars()` function converts special characters to HTML entities. This means that it will replace HTML characters like < and > with < and >. This prevents attackers from exploiting the code by injecting HTML or Javascript code (Cross-site Scripting attacks) in forms.

So I thought, if the variable `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is returning the filename (in this case - contact.php, there lies my problem so just replace `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` with `contact` without the .php extension like below:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(contact);?>" id="contactform">
```

And Voilà, it worked!  But I'm not sure if this workaround creates a vulnerability for hackers.

Answer (score -1):

Remove action value to submit on self page.

```
   <form method="post" action="" id="contactform">
```

I hope this will work

Comment: unfortunately this does not work.  still has the .php extention after submit with validation errors.

Comment: do me a favor and delete this answer so it doesn't look like it's answered to stack users.

Comment: Thanks man.  I appreciate you leaving a poor answer up so nobody else answers.

Comment: downvoting me won't hurt me with over 1000 rep.  it will take you many years to get to this level if you keep guessing at answers.